# Swift PromiseKit. Do GET requests multiple times one by one. Pyramid of doom with PromiseKit

Tags: json, swift, promisekit

I am doing multiple GET requests to the URL, it returns me some JSON data, which I decode into the class. From this class I extract attribute - **id: Int**, this **id** is part of a URL which I build to make another GET Request.

In other words:
JSON fetched from URL -> JSON Decoded -> id extracted -> new url built -> JSON fetched from new URL -> JSON Decoded... and this process is repeated n times.

What I have for now is just the same pyramid of doom, but using PromiseKit notation:

```
        func fetch_analysis_dataTask(url: String) -> Promise<(data: Data, response: URLResponse)> {
            let urlRequest = APIConnect.urlRequest(endPoint: url, method: .GET, data: nil)
            return URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: urlRequest).validate()
        }

        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Async call")
        let urlRequest = APIConnect.urlRequest(endPoint: "test?patient_id=3730", method: .GET, data: nil)

        firstly {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: urlRequest).validate()
        }.map {
            try JSONDecoder().decode([TestWrapper].self, from: $0.data)
        }.done { testWrappers in
            var tests = [Test]()
            for testWrapper in testWrappers {
                if testWrapper.test != nil {
                    tests.append(testWrapper.test!)
                }
            }

            let testID = tests.first!.id!
            let urlRequest = APIConnect.urlRequest(endPoint: "analysis/" + String(testID), method: .GET, data: nil)

            firstly {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: urlRequest).validate()
            }.map {
                try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0.data, options: .allowFragments)
            }.done { data in
                XCTAssert(data != nil)
                expectation.fulfill()
            }.catch { error in
                print(error)
                XCTAssert(false)
                expectation.fulfill()
            }
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 20)
    }
```

However I do not see the way how to do it, but I am sure there is, or?

Comment: you can use `when` declaration of the PromiseKit, please check this -> https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/promisekit-chaining-3c957a8ace24

Answer (score 0):

If you use `then` instead of `done` you can return a promise and it will continue the chain. Something like this:

```
let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Async call")
let urlRequest = APIConnect.urlRequest(endPoint: "test?patient_id=3730", method: .GET, data: nil)

firstly {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: urlRequest).validate()
}.map {
    try JSONDecoder().decode([TestWrapper].self, from: $0.data)
}.then { testWrappers in
    var tests = [Test]()
    for testWrapper in testWrappers {
        if testWrapper.test != nil {
            tests.append(testWrapper.test!)
        }
    }

    let testID = tests.first!.id!
    let urlRequest = APIConnect.urlRequest(endPoint: "analysis/" + String(testID), method: .GET, data: nil)
    return URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: urlRequest).validate()
}.map {
    try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0.data, options: .allowFragments)
}.done { data in
    XCTAssert(data != nil)
    expectation.fulfill()
}.catch { error in
    print(error)
    XCTAssert(false)
    expectation.fulfill()
}

waitForExpectations(timeout: 20)
```

PS. I've had the compiler getting confused with complex chains. Annotating the return values could help, but what I usually end up doing is trying to make all `map`, `then`, `ensure`, etc. calls have a single statement, which might mean using more `map`s.